# JQuery onchange isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm trying to test an onchange event and i tried a lot of things and none seems do have any effect, can you guys tell me why isn't this working? Also i went to check the source code of the year of birth select and i get this:

```
<select id="account_year_Of_Birth" name="account[year_Of_Birth]"><option value=""></option>
```

I also tried with that id but again, nothing...

In my view:

```
   <div class="control-group">
      <%= f.label "Date of Birth (YYYY-MM-DD)", :class => 'control-label' %>
      <div class="controls">
        <%= f.select :year_Of_Birth , options_for_select((Time.now.year - 100)..(Time.zone.now.year )), :include_blank => true, :id => "year"%>
        <%= f.select :month_Of_Birth, 1..12 , :include_blank=> true, :id => "month"  %>
        <%= f.select :day_Of_Birth, 1..31 , :include_blank => true, :id => "day"  %>
      </div>
      <%= error_span(@account[:year_Of_Birth]) %>
    </div>
```

In my application.js:

```
$( "account_year_Of_Birth" ).on('change',function() {
        alert( "alert" );
    });
```

Comment: try to add # to your selector `$("#account_year_Of_Birth")`

Answer (score 1):

You need a '#' in your selector:

```
$( "#account_year_Of_Birth" ).on('change',function() {
    alert( "alert" );
});
```

Comment: yeah when i copied the code i was trying without the # but when i trie with the result is the same (none)

Comment: Where are you including the code in the html document?